# Replace whole word only

Tags: replacement, string-manipulation

To replace these words as given by the rule:

```
source = {"C10", "C10T11"};
repl = { "C10" -> "01C10", "C10T11" -> "02C10T11"};
```

`StringReplace` doesn't understand that I want the rule to apply only to whole words, apparently:

```
In[89]:= StringReplace[source, repl]

Out[89]= {"01C10", "01C10T11"}
```

Where the error in the second element seems to arise from matching the part of the source string, instead of looking for whole word matches. Please advise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** Evidently I missed the thrust of the question.  Please feel free to "un-accept" this answer in favor of Mathe172's answer and I'll be able to delete this.

If you are looking for entire string matching only you should as Mathe172 said use `ReplaceAll` (i.e. `source /. repl`  equiv to `ReplaceAll[source,repl]`), not `StringReplace`, whose entire purpose is substring replace.

For entire string replacement it will be *much* faster to use `ReplaceAll`, and you won't have to worry about sort order.

I misunderstood the question to be dealing with frustration at sub-expressions getting matched *first*, not sub-expressions getting matched at all.

---

orig answer:

What's happening is that your short string is getting replaced first because of order of your replacement rules.

You can do the following:

```
sortedReplaceLongestFirst = Sort[repl, ! OrderedQ[StringLength[First[#]] & /@ {#1, #2}] &];
```

yielding:

> {"C10T11" -> "02C10T11", "C10" -> "01C10"}

Applying:

```
StringReplace[source, sortedReplaceLongestFirst ]
```

gives,

> {"01C10", "02C10T11"}

Comment: Thanks! ... a bit more complicated than I thought, and I actually have a long list of words to replace...

Comment: Yes. If there is a chance that you are pattern matching on substrings you want to do a sort such that your rules are ranked from longest matching substring to shortest.  Maybe this update is a little clearer.

Comment: `Reverse@SortBy[repl, StringLength@*First]` should do the same thing as your sorting expression

Comment: Also, I don't think that this is what the question asks for - if you remove the second replacement rule, this approach still incorrectly replaces parts of the second string.

Comment: So far the sorting is giving the answer I was looking for, sorry if question is unclear.

Answer (score 9):

If you really only want to replace full words, just use `ReplaceAll`:

```
 source /. repl
 Out[1]:=  {"01C10", "02C10T11"}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I misread the point of the question.   (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I would use `ReplaceAll` as in @Mathe172's answer. But, if you have to use `StringReplace`, you can change `rpl` to include information that you *want the rule to apply only to whole words*:

```
repl2 = WordBoundary ~~ # ~~ WordBoundary -> #2 & @@@ repl;

StringReplace[source, repl2]
```

> {"01C10", "02C10T11"}

Answer (score 3):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
source = {"C10", "C10T11", "NoReplacements"};
repl = {"C10" -> "01C10", "C10T11" -> "02C10T11"};
    
Lookup[repl, #, #] & /@ source
```

> {"01C10", "02C10T11", "NoReplacements"}